# Fields capabilities

Tags: entities, nodes

I am trying to enable a field in one of my content-types to be a sort of selection within a selection and I need some help doing so. Basically, I would like to have a field where the user selects from a more encompassing list (e.g., buildings) from which she is then presented with a more narrow list (perhaps room number, following the example). Is this possible to do with fields in Drupal? I understand that I could simply make two fields but I think it'd be much nicer to have this list within a list. Again, I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your list is coming from `Taxonomy` then you can use [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you! Is there any way to do the same without having the list come from Taxonomy?

Comment: where you are getting your list from?

Comment: It's not a large one so I was planning to simply input it manually into the allowed values body

Comment: I would suggest to use taxonomy only because you can reuse it and it integrates well with views and other modules.

Comment: If you dont like the fact that say the Taxonomies are viewable themselves on urls, install [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) and hide the taxonomy entry menu paths.